# Fix Core Data Fail

Tags: ios, core-data, crash, core-data-migration

I have an app in the app store that uses Core Data and I have to release an update by tomorrow. However, I am experiencing some problems with Core Data.I by mistake made changes to my model in Core Data and now my app is crashing. I tried migrating the data but the app still crashes when I updated it on my iPhone. Is there anyway to fix it?

Thank you so much for your help!

**EDIT:** I am trying to add the .mom file to the app but I can not get it into the Bundle:

[image]

**EDIT 2:** Do I delete the entirely Planner.xcdatamodeld:

[image]

Comment: Just revert the changes in git and get back your model? Or, wait, you don't use version controll?

Comment: Time machine is my fallback… if you can do so you are saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recover the original Core Data model from the production app's bundle.

Use Finder to open the app bundle (Show Package Contents) and look for a .mom file or a .momd directory.

Copy the file or directory to some location outside the bundle.

Create a new XCode project with Core Data.

In XCode select the newly created projects Core Data model.

Go to the XCode Editor -> Import menu and select the .mom file you have just copied, if need be find the correct version in the .momd directory.

You should now have the model in XCode, save and copy the model file to you original project...

In XCode delete the incorrect model from your project (remember to save a copy first so you have a copy of the new changes)

Use the XCode Add File to... menu to add the old model to the original project

Now compile and run the app to confirm it opens the old file correctly

Now add a new model version and add the changes to this new version - make sure you select the new model version in XCode before making changes

[image]

Comment: Yes delete the old incorrect model from the project but select the Remove Reference option, that way the file itself is not deleted, its just removed from the project so you can add it back later.

Comment: Thanks also how would XCode know to use the "Plannerfix.xcdatamodeld"

Comment: Probably also a good idea to rename it (the old one) to something else once it has been removed and then in XCode rename the one you have just imported (PlannerFix) to be the same as it was in the original app

Comment: Unless you are specifically referencing the model name the app will find all models in the application bundle and merge them - which is why you must dereference the incorrect model

Answer (score 1):

You should revert your model to the one that you have in App Store. Then you should `Add new model version` of your Core Data model. If you can't revert to that model you should try to make it exactly as it was.

After you've done a new model version, you should select that one and make the changes.

Comment: How can I revert the model to the one in the App Store? Sorry for the stupid question...

Comment: I don't mean using the one you have in the App Store. Just having the same file as you used when you uploaded your app :)

Comment: Yes but I have made changes to that file ... How can I get it as it was before?

Comment: If you don't have any copies/version control or anything, you have to remember how it was. Don't you have a local Git? If you do, you could probably right click on your model and Choose "Source control". You could also do this from the menu "Source Control" and then "Discard all changes"

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use Git (which is really, really bad, by the way), you can just install your app from the App Store and use some iPhone File Manager to get the old mom file from your app. It would be in */apps/yorapp/youapp.app/* folder with **.mom** extension 
Try [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/), for example, it's free.

Comment: Nice one, didn't think about that. @Abdullah, do this if you don't have version control.

Comment: Hi, Just one question... I have the .mom file but what do I do with it?

Comment: Am I supposed to add it to my project?

Comment: you add it to the bundle of your model file; replacing the one that was there. Open your projects core data model file, the one you accidentally changed; inside you'll see the .mom file. Replace that with the .mom you extracted from the suggestion above.

Comment: you're showing the view from within Xcode, we're talking about the file system bundle. Show bundle contents... Also, it looks like you did have a versioned model to begin with, and just forgot to add another version when you accidentally changed the file last? The easier thing might be to grab the entire .xcdatamodel file from within the app bundle and replace your projects' model with that. Then start over with your next version, and introduce your recent changes again, properly this time

Comment: @wkhatch Can you please provide pictures or a video on how to do it? So sorry but I am so confused.

Comment: right/control click your model file in the finder; select "Show Package Contents"...

Comment: @wkhatch What do I do next?

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637337/is-it-possible-to-recover-my-deleted-xcdatamodel-file